# Kdenlive website go

Tags: kdenlive

I know this is the stupidest question ever but where is kdenlive website ??

I was am looking for it on google but can not find it anywhere

is that project still active ??

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with Ubuntu so offtopic ;) If closed feel free to delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is down: http://kdenlive.org/ shows...

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is
>   either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>
> www.kdenlive.org Sun Aug 4 18:18:25 2013 Apache

Comment: so it is simply down and will reappear ??

Comment: Or dead forever. I would advice emailing the webmaster (see the mail link on the site) ;)

Comment: Also see this thread on the KDE forums: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=112105

Comment: As of 2016, the page is back.

Answer (score 1):

The [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdenlive/) page is alive.